# GridView search button

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

How to place search button in DataGridView cell in Windows Application like font selecting in control property window in Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a direct answer to your question but you might want to look at Object List View

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

It actually wraps a ListView but has a lot of capabilities including reading data from a database as I recall.  This provides for in-cell editors.  For standard things like colors it has a built in cell editor.  If that does not work then you can roll your own.